# Run threads for a certain amount of time - before being killed

Tags: go

How do I run 10 threads, for 30 seconds each, and then return to the program execution? For example, I want

1. 10 threads to be spawned and ran for 30 seconds.
2. Then all threads killed
3. Then `second()` to run (i.e. after all threads have finished executing)

So far I have the following however, when I do this, the threads (obviously) keep executing and CPU usage remains at 100% after 30s:

```
func main(){
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++{
        go thread()
    }
    time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)
    second()
}

func thread() {
    for {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6807784/1371064

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Golang context. Here's some of my code when I was learning it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

func main() {
    someHandler()
}

func someHandler() {
    //Create a new context with a timeout duration of six seconds. You also get a cancel function you can call early. 
    //You can also have context end at a certain time, instead of a timeout
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*time.Duration(6))

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go doStuff(ctx, i)
    }

    select {
    case <- ctx.Done():
        log.Println("Got a cancel request")
        return
    case <-time.After(time.Second * time.Duration(5)):
        //Here I'm actually ending it earlier than the timeout with cancel().
        log.Println("Timed out")
        cancel()
    }

}

func doStuff(ctx context.Context, num int) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("Done working")
            return
        default:
            fmt.Println("go", num, "working")
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
$ go run app.go 
go 0 working
go 4 working
go 2 working
go 3 working
go 1 working
go 1 working
go 0 working
go 4 working
go 3 working
go 2 working
go 0 working
go 4 working
go 2 working
go 1 working
go 3 working
go 4 working
go 3 working
go 0 working
go 2 working
go 1 working
go 3 working
go 4 working
go 1 working
go 0 working
go 2 working
2016/10/01 23:25:23 Timed out
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a wait group and a "done" channel to cancel running go routines and and synchronize their exits before calling `second`. Some really cool stuff on the topic can be read here https://blog.golang.org/pipelines.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    //create a "done" channel that will be used to signal to all go routines running thread to quit
    done := make(chan interface{})

    //create a wait group to sync all go routines before continuing program execution
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        //increment waitgroup
        wg.Add(1)
        go thread(done, wg)
    }
    //zzzz...
    time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)
    //close the done channel
    close(done)
    //wait for all go routines to quit
    wg.Wait()
    //move on
    second()
}

func thread(done chan interface{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    working := true
    for working {
        //use a select statement to do work until done channel is closed
        select {
        case <-done:
            //end the loop
            working = false
        default:
            fmt.Println("doing work...")
        }
    }
}

func second() {
    fmt.Println("program complete")
}
```