# How to start/stop a feature by calling a struct method

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

Please see the following example.

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/ZEEgsOqcPb5)

```
type runner struct{}

func (r *runner) StopProcessing() {
    // how to stop?
}

func (r *runner) StartProcessing() {

    go func() {
        for {
            fmt.Println("doing stuff")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }()

}
```

As you can see I have a struct which does stuff, it's "running". It starts running when I call the `run.StartProcessing()` method. It then fires an endless running `for{}`-loop in a goroutine. Great, but I also want to be able to stop this process. And I really don't know how to achieve this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Linking to code helps the community less. The playground links are nice, but the core important code should be placed in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop a goroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807590/how-to-stop-a-goroutine)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a context to get timeouts and cancelation, without requiring any extra API.

```
type runner struct{}

func (r *runner) StartProcessing(ctx context.Context) {
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return
            default:
            }
            fmt.Println("doing stuff")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }()
}
```

This gives you the flexibility to set a timeout, or cancel it at any time. You can also make use of existing contexts which may want to timeout or cancel sooner without your knowledge.

```
// normal timeout after 10 seconds
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()
run.StartProcessing(ctx)

// decide to cancel early
time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
cancel()
```

Answer (score -1):

By using a channel to signal when to break out of a goroutine. The relevant part of your code would look something like this

```
type runner struct {
    stop chan bool
}

func (r *runner) StopProcessing() {
    r.stop <- true
}

func (r *runner) StartProcessing() {
    r.stop = make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for {
            fmt.Println("doing stuff")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            select {
            case _ = <-r.stop:
                close(r.stop)
                return
            default:
            }
        }
    }()
}
```

You can see a full example here https://play.golang.org/p/OUn18Cprs0I

Comment: Beat me to it. Probably best to close the channel before the break.

Comment: Agreed. Updated the code for both the answer and playground. Also, I think returning out of the function is more definite than breaking out of the loop

Comment: That was how I did it when I was about to post my version.

Comment: The channel here does not need to be closed, nor should the receiver be responsible for closing it.

Comment: Why not? You need to make an actual argument if you want to convince people. StartProcessing() creates the channel and StopProcessing() closes the channel, so if StartProcessing() is called again a new channel will be created.

Comment: @MadWombat: closing a channel is not a cleanup action, it's a type of message. The advice to not have the receiver close a channel is generally sounds advice to avoid sending on a closed channel.

Comment: This channel is only used to start/stop the processing routine. It is created on start and closed on stop and that is the only place where it is ever used. If this was a channel used to transfer actual data between multiple goroutines, I would agree with you.

Comment: My comment was only for code quality, as it would not pass our code review. Do with it what you will.

Answer (score -1):

You might try something like this...  You might not need atomic but this works.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync/atomic"
)

var trip = int64(0)

type runner struct{}

func (r *runner) StopProcessing() {
    atomic.AddInt64(&trip, 1)
}

func (r *runner) StartProcessing() {
    go func() {
        for {
            if trip > 0 {
                break
            }
            fmt.Println("doing stuff")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }()
}

func newRunner() *runner {
    return &runner{}
}

func main() {
    run := newRunner()
    run.StartProcessing() 

    // now wait 4 seconds and the kill the process
    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
    run.StopProcessing()
}
```

Comment: Using global variables to keep temporary state is generally frowned upon

Comment: Also, using int64 where its value will ever be 0 or 1 is not a good thing either. Although you can call StopProcessing() repeatedly and it will keep incrementing. Also, since there is a single goroutine running, no need to use atomic updates.

Comment: You cannot read a value concurrently, even with an atomic write. You must safely load the value, or better yet, use the builtin concurrency features of the language, like a channel.