# Best way to stop a single goroutine?

Tags: go, goroutine

In my program I have several go-routines who are essentially running endless processes. Why? you may ask, long story short it is the purpose of my entire application so it's out of question to change that. I would like to give users the ability to stop a single go-routine. I understand that I can use channel to signal the go-routines to stop, however there may be cases where I have, say, 10 go-routines running and I only want to stop 1. The issue is that the number of go-routines I want to run is dynamic and based on user input. What is the best way for me to add the ability to stop a go-routine dynamically and allow for singles to be stopped without the rest?

Comment: Use https://golang.org/pkg/context/ for cancellation of goroutines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop a goroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807590/how-to-stop-a-goroutine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need design a map to manage contexts.

Assume you've already known usage of context. It might look like:

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx.TODO())

go func(ctx){
    for {

        select {

           case <-ctx.Done():
                return
           default:
              // job
        }
    }
}(ctx)

cancel()
```

Ok, now you can convert your question to another, it might called 'how to manage contexts of many goroutine'

```golang
type GoroutineManager struct{
    m sync.Map
}
func (g *GoroutineManager) Add(cancel context.CancelFunc, key string)) {
    g.m.Store(key, cancel)
}

func (g *GoroutineManager) KillGoroutine(key string) {
    cancel, exist := g.m.Load(key)
    if exist {
        cancel()
    }
}
```

Ok, Now you can manage your goroutine like :

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx.TODO())

manager.Add(cancel, "routine-job-1")
go func(ctx){
    for {

        select {

           case <-ctx.Done():
                return
           default:
              // job
        }
    }
}(ctx)


// kill it as your wish
manager.KillGoroutine("routine-job-1")
```

Comment: The g.m.Load(key) returns an `any` type and bool, how does one now do a type conversion from `any` to `cancelFunc`. My editor gives the error:
"invalid operation: cannot call non-function cancel (variable of type any)"