# Stop a goroutine if it is running

Tags: go, goroutine

I have a question similar to [How to stop a goroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807590/how-to-stop-a-goroutine) with a small twist. I don't know for sure if the goroutine is running.

```golang
var quit = make(chan bool)

func f1() {
    go func() {
        t := time.NewTimer(time.Minute)
        select {
        case <-t.C:
            // Do stuff
        case <-quit:
            return
        }
    }()
}

func f2() {
    quit <- true
}
```

If `f2()` is called less than a minute after `f1()`, then the goroutine returns. However, if it is called later than one minute, the goroutine will have already returned and `f2()` would block.
I want `f2()` to cancel the goroutine if it is running and do nothing otherwise.

What I'm trying to achieve here is to perform a task if and only if it is not canceled within a minute of creation.

Clarifications:

- There is nothing to stop `f2()` from being called more than once.
- There is only one goroutine running at a time. The caller of `f1()` will make sure that it's not called more than once per minute.

Answer (score 10):

Use contexts.

Run `f1` with the context which may be cancelled.
Run `f2` with the associated cancellation function.

```golang
func f1(ctx context.Context) {
    go func(ctx context.Context) {
        t := time.NewTimer(time.Minute)
        select {
        case <-t.C:
            // Do stuff
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        }
    }(ctx)
}

func f2(cancel context.CancelFunc) {
    cancel()
}
```

And later, to coordinate the two functions, you would do this:

```golang
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    f1(ctx)
    f2(cancel)
```

You can also experiment with the `context.WithTimeout` function to incorporate externally-defined timeouts.

In the case where you don't know whether there is a goroutine running already, you can initialize the `ctx` and `cancel` variables like above, but don't pass them into anything. This avoids having to check for `nil`.

Remember to treat ctx and cancel as variables to be copied, not as references, because you don't want multiple goroutines to share memory - that may cause a race condition.

Comment: Can `f1` be called again with the same `ctx` instance after it's cancelled or a new `ctx` needs to be created?

Comment: You should create a new context, otherwise it may have already been cancelled.

Answer (score -1):

You can give the channel a buffer size of 1.  This means you can send one value to it without blocking, even if that value is not received right away (or at all).

```golang
var quit = make(chan bool, 1)
```

I think the top answer is better, this is just another solution that could translate to other situations.

Comment: That is true, but the next goroutine will quit immediately as the channel already has an element.

Comment: Yes. The same problem also applies to the `close(quit)` method.  The channel will be closed forever, and any subsequent reads will behave the same.  If you need to quit each goroutine individually, they should not share a `quit` channel.  And if you want to quit them all at the same time and forever, you should use `close(quit)`.

Comment: I probably didn't explain the issue properly. There will be only one goroutine active at a time and that's why there is only one channel. But there will be subsequent calls to `f1()` (after the existing goroutine is done) that would create a new instance.

Comment: It's a bad idea to reuse quit channels, as it leads to exactly the kinds of problems you're having right now. There is no clean way to "reset" a channel.

Comment: You're probably right. Not sure how to solve this otherwise though.
Thanks for the answer anyway :)