# How to make this golang for-select code work?

Tags: go, select, goroutine

### Question

How to make the below code print "QUIT" after 3 seconds?

### Code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    quit := make(chan struct{})
    tasks := make(chan struct{})

    go func(){
      time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
      tasks <- struct{}{}
    }()

    go func(){
      time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
      quit <- struct{}{}
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("QUIT")
            return
        case <-tasks:
            fmt.Println("Doing")
            // do some long time jobs more than 10 seconds
            time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        }
    }
}
```

### Observations

The above code prints "Doing". and sleep 10 seconds, then print "QUIT".
How to interrupt this sleep, let it receive `quit` channel after 3 seconds and print "QUIT"?

It seems `select` is blocked by `case tasks`, and it will not receive from the `quit` channel after 3 seconds.

Comment: delete `return`

Comment: *It seems select is blocked by case tasks* No, the program just ends since you return.

Comment: *How to interrupt this sleep* - what problem are you trying to solve here? "Kill" a blocking operation?

Comment: How to make it quit after 3 seconds?  I've updated this question.

Comment: Assume there is a time consuming job inside `case tasks`, which longer than 10 seconds, So how can I interrupt this job when I send a `quit` channel signal?

Comment: you would not run the time-consuming (and blocking) job in `main`. use a goroutine which you can cancel, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47302930/10197418

Comment: See also this https://golangbyexample.com/select-statement-with-timeout-go/

Answer (score 2):

To signal end of an asynchronous task it is a best practice to close the channel, this is rather important to prevent many missuse that leads to various deadlocks.
In your original code I would have written `close(quite)` rather than `quit <- struct{}{}`
Remember, read on a closed does not block and always return the zero value, that is the trick.

Anyways, appart from this, an elegant way to solve your problem is to use a combination of both `context.Context` and `time.After`.

`time.After` will help you block on a selectable task set.

`context.Context` is better suited to handle this kind of signals.

https://play.golang.org/p/ZVsZw3P-YHd

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("start")
    defer log.Println("end")
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    tasks := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) // a job
        tasks <- struct{}{}
    }()

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second) // a job
        cancel()
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            log.Println("QUIT")
            return
        case <-tasks:
            log.Println("Doing")
            // do some long time jobs more than 10 seconds
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return
            case <-time.After(time.Second * 10):
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second job is running for 10 seconds, so it will block the loop for that time, and the signal you sent into the `quit` channel will not be received until this job is complete.

To interrupt the time-consuming job, maybe you can split it into another goroutine. Something like this would do:

```
go func() {
  for {
    select {
    case <-tasks:
      fmt.Println("Doing")
      // do some long time jobs more than 10 seconds
      time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    }   
  }   
}() 

<-quit
fmt.Println("QUIT")
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use [sync.WaitGroup.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func worker(msg string, duration time.Duration, doing bool, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    time.Sleep(duration)

    fmt.Println(msg)

    if doing {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    msgs := [2]string{"QUIT", "Doing"}
    durations := [2]time.Duration{3 * time.Second, 1 * time.Second}
    doing := [2]bool{false, true}

    for i, msg := range msgs {
        wg.Add(1)

        go worker(msg, durations[i], doing[i], &wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```