# Cancel all goroutine when one of goroutine failed

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

Cancel all goroutines when one of goroutines failed.

1. parent job consist of 3 child jobs.
2. parent job have 5 second timeout.
3. If all child jobs complete within the timeout of the parent process(5s), the program terminates normally.
4. If one of child jobs occurred error within the timeout of the parent process(5s), all child process should stop.
5. If one of child jobs could not completed within the timeout of the parent process(5s), the program return error.

And this is my code.

I trying to verify number 5 case. So when job's name is `b` time.Sleep(10s; more than 5s).

```golang
package stackoverflow

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "sync"
    "testing"
    "time"

    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

func TestTask(t *testing.T) {

    err := parent(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("main error: %v\n", err)
    }
    log.Println("main done")

}

func parent(ctx context.Context) error {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second*5)
    defer cancel()
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    fromChild := make(chan error)
    var err error
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        defer wg.Done()
        select {
        case err = <-fromChild:
            fmt.Printf("Parent: child go routines return error : %s \n", err.Error())
            return
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Printf("Parent: context ended. : %s \n", ctx.Err())
            return
        }
    }(wg)

    jobs := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    for _, job := range jobs {
        wg.Add(1)
        go processChild(ctx, job, wg, fromChild)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Printf("done.\n")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
func processChild(ctx context.Context, name string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan<- error) {
    defer wg.Done()
    log.Printf("processsing %s job\n", name)

    c := time.After(time.Second * 60)
    go func() {
        select {
        case <-c:
            ch <- errors.New("error occurred.")
            return
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        }
    }()

    if name == "a" {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    }
    if name == "b" {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 10) //  when parent context timeout happens during this line, stop this goroutine.
    }
    log.Printf("done %s job\n", name)
}
```

But When I test it took 10s.

```bash
$ go test -v . -count=1
=== RUN   TestTask
2023/11/21 10:57:08 processsing c job
2023/11/21 10:57:08 done c job
2023/11/21 10:57:08 processsing b job
2023/11/21 10:57:08 processsing a job
2023/11/21 10:57:10 done a job
Parent: context ended. : context deadline exceeded
done.
2023/11/21 10:57:18 main done
--- PASS: TestTask (10.00s) // it tooks 10s
PASS
```

What I want to do in processChild is

1. sensing parent context's timeout. stop all child goroutines.
2. if error occured in child goroutine, return error and also stop all child goroutines.

Is this impossible?

Comment: `parent` only returns nil, so why would there be an error in `TestTask`? You are still waiting on the `processChild` goroutines, which are not aware of the context. You either need to make those context-aware, or abandon waiting for them after the timeout.

Comment: @JimB I edited my code. Take a look please.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807590/how-to-stop-a-goroutine